# Recover filenames for doc and RTF

Tags: linux, bash

I have some hundreds of .doc and .rtf files, which lost their original names after recovery from a damaged hard disk. Basically they look like this:

```
f132765720.rtf
f136246056.rtf
f146124320.doc
f147595288.docx
f131673632.rtf
```

I can read the files without any problem. How can I recreate meaningful filenames from files' content in Linux?

Sample file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41225253/example.rtf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below will find all `.docx` and `.rtf` files in the current directory and rename them to `first_few_words.rtf` or `docx`. First you need to install [`catdoc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/catdoc). On Debian and its derivatives you can do that with

```
sudo apt-get install catdoc
```

Oddly enough, `catdoc` gives me a segfault when I try it on a `docx` I have, so use `docx2txt` for the doc files instead:

```
sudo apt-get install docx2txt
```

Once you have `catdoc` and `docx` installed, `cd` to the directory that contains your files and run this:

```
for file in *rtf; do 
  name=$(catdoc "$file" | grep . | head -1 | sed 's/ /_/g') &&
  mv "$file" "$name".rtf;
done
for file in *docx; do 
  name=$(docx2txt < "$file" | grep . | head -1 | sed 's/ /_/g') &&
  mv "$file" "$name".docx;
done
```

CAUTION: This will **delete** the original files, make sure you make a back up first, just in case.

EXPLANATION: both utilities convert `docx` or `rtf` to text, I then select the first non empty line of that text, convert spaces to underscores (it will make your life easier in the long run) and rename the files accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To the answer provided by @terdon I'd like to add that I found that if I prefix every file name with a creation date, it would be a big help.

For .docx files date can be found this way:

```
unzip -p example.docx | grep dcterms:created |
    grep -o [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] | head -1
```

For .doc files:

```
antiword -x db example.doc | grep date | grep -o '[0-9-]*'
```

For .rtf files:

```
grep -o '\\creatim\\yr[0-9]*\\mo[0-9]*\\dy[0-9]*' example.rtf |
    grep -o [0-9]* | tr "\n" -
```